# Sync operation batch maximum size

Tags: extjs

I initiate a store sync operation on an Ajax store:

```
store.sync();
```

The server API that processes the changes has a low timeout, and needs some time to decode the JSON. The decoding seems to be O^2 in the length of the input. So while 100 items run without noticeable delay, when 3000 new items are added to a store, the server operation times out even before the input is processed. I cannot increase the server timeout to such values that 3000 items can be processed in time.

The 3000 items are added automatically using a single call to `store.add`, because smaller `add` operations put additional strain on the grids and combos bound to the store.

```
store.add([{...},{...},{...},...])
```

Is there a possibility to tell the ExtJS proxy to send smaller chunks to the server, for instance up to 100 items at a time?

Comment: Are you using this store for grid/combo ?